# Loading View Controllers in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a UIPageViewController to scroll through 3 view controllers. The goal is to be able to swipe left and right to navigate them, which I'm able to do with the following code. The issue is that on opening the app for the first time, the navigation bars load in the wrong place and need a full second to conform to constraints. The nav bars load higher than they should be. I'm wondering why there's such a delay in them loading.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var myViewControllers = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue:UIViewController())

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let pvc = segue.destinationViewController as! UIPageViewController

        pvc.dataSource = self

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

        var vc0 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController1") as! UIViewController
        var vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController2") as! UIViewController
        var vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as! UIViewController


        self.myViewControllers = \[vc0, vc1, vc2\]

        pvc.setViewControllers(\[myViewControllers\[1\]\], direction:.Forward, animated:false, completion:nil)

        println("Loaded")
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!+1
        if currentIndex >= self.myViewControllers.count {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers\[currentIndex\]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!-1
        if currentIndex < 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers\[currentIndex\]
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I experienced the same problem and I had no option but remove all auto-layout constraints and set up layout manually. Not sure if you're using or not auto layout here

Comment: Yeah I'm using it. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, I removed auto layout constraints and worked on the layout manually

Comment: @ClaudioRedi can I embed navigation controllers in the page view controller instead of view controllers?